# group and sum entities by property in java 8

Tags: java, group-by, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to regroup some entities by an object, here is an exemple where I tried to group by typeOfArticle while summing by price. So my question is how can i do it with java8? :

```
public class Article{
   private Integer id;
   private String name;
   private String prenom;
   private TypeOfArticle typeOfArticle;
   private double price;
   ....    }
```

the second class :

```
public TypeOfArticle{
  private Integer id;
  .......}
```

i've alreadey try this :

```
  ListOfArticle.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(ListOfArticle :: getTypeOfArticle, Collectors.summingInt(ListOfArticle::getPrice)));
```

Comment: What is your attempt? What is your question? Your example doesn't show anything of what you tried, and it's difficult to know what you need help with.

Comment: i'm trying to get total price of typeOfArticle.

Comment: Yes, I see that you're trying to do that. So where are you stuck? Do you have questions about any documentation, or have a specific issue with your code? Without showing your attempt, we have no way of knowing your experience level. If you haven't made an attempt yet, go do that.

Comment: my question is how can i do it with java 8? i already read some documents but it's about how to group by properties. not by another object

Comment: Wouldn't it be the same way? `Collectors.groupingBy(Article::getType)`

Comment: Collectors.groupingBy(article :: getArticle, Collectors.summingInt(article ::getPrice)));

Comment: Awesome! Please show exactly what you tried in the question. I'm trying to explain how you can improve your question so that you don't keep getting downvotes.

Comment: can u repost your answer ! it's working ! thanks   ListOfArticle.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(ListOfArticle :: ListOfArticle .getTypeOfArticle().getId(), Collectors.summingInt(ListOfArticle::getPrice)));

Comment: Did you override `equals` in your `TypeOfArticle` class? That's probably why you can't group by article type.

Comment: i got the ansewer just see the post below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how it work for me :

```
listOfArticle.stream().collect( Collectors.groupingBy(article -> article .getTypeOfArticle().getId(), Collectors.summingInt(article::getPrice)));
```

where

```
List<Article> listOfArticle = new ArrayList<Article>();
```

Comment: but it actually does

Comment: :: to -> sorry.

Comment: It’s good that you start following the Java naming conventions, i.e. let variables start with a lower case letter, but note that `Article` in the lambda expression is a variable (lambda parameter), unlike `Article` in the method reference which indeed refers to the class `Article`.

Comment: It’s correct in the sense of “working”, but you should follow the naming convention, i.e. use `article -> article.getTypeOfArticle().getId()`, because `article` is a variable here. By the way, since Java 7, you can omit the type repetition when constructing generic objects, i.e. you can use `List<Article> listOfArticle = new ArrayList<>();`.